# Counting number of rows between 2 dates and 1 where clause

Tags: mysql

I've a mysql table with me

[image]

Now we want to do some calculations like this

- count date wise for all courses enrolled
- count where course id = 2 for date > start_date AND date < end_date

*Expected output where we calculate all courses enrolled*

[image: Expected output where we calculate all courses enrolled]

*Expected output where we calculate all courses enrolled where course id = 2*

*[image]

*expected output where course_id = 2 AND date range is between 2022-11-15 to 2022-11-13*

[image]

**The query which I've right now**

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(registered_on) 
FROM courses_enrolled 
WHERE course_id = 1 
GROUP BY DATE(registered_on), course_id 
ORDER BY registered_on desc;
```

Comment: which one have you achieved and which one you want to achieve?

Comment: To count the amount of rows using some conditions use not `COUNT(*) WHERE {condition}` but `SUM( {condition} )`. In this variant the condition shouldn't produce NULL.

Comment: Please post table structure and example data as text and not as image. What's your actual problem? Your query should work fine for case 2. You just need to add some additional `where` conditions for case 3 and remove the grouping by `course_id ` for case 1. But it of course won't produce any rows with count 0

Comment: @Akina I don't know why I didn't think of it, simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of calendar table approach here:

```sql
SELECT d.dt AS date, COUNT(ce.id) AS cnt
FROM (
    SELECT '2022-11-12' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-11-13' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-11-14' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-11-15'
) d
LEFT JOIN courses_enrolled ce
   ON DATE(ce.registered_on) = d.dt AND
      ce.course_id = 2
GROUP BY d.dt
ORDER BY d.dt;
```

The calendar table ensures that all dates you want in the output appear.  In practice, you may replace the subquery in `d` with a bona-fide table containing all dates of interest.  The left join ensures that no dates are dropped which have no matching courses on that day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8 you can use a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series) to create your date range.

For all enrolled courses for given date range -

```
WITH RECURSIVE calendar (date) AS (
    SELECT '2022-11-13' # start date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM calendar
    WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2022-11-15' # end date
)
SELECT COUNT(ce.id) count_all, c.date
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN courses_enrolled ce
    ON ce.registered_on BETWEEN c.date AND (c.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
GROUP BY c.date
ORDER BY c.date DESC;
```

Note the use of BETWEEN start AND end of day in the join criteria. For a small dataset this offers negligible benefit but on a large dataset it would allow for use of an index on `registered_on`, which could offer significantly improved performance.

Or for just the selected course -

```
WITH RECURSIVE calendar (date) AS (
    SELECT '2022-11-13' # start date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM calendar
    WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2022-11-15' # end date
)
SELECT COUNT(ce.id) count_selected_course, c.date
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN courses_enrolled ce
    ON ce.registered_on BETWEEN c.date AND (c.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
    AND ce.course_id = 2
GROUP BY c.date
ORDER BY c.date DESC;
```

Or counting both at the same time -

```
WITH RECURSIVE calendar (date) AS (
    SELECT '2022-11-13' # start date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM calendar
    WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2022-11-15' # end date
)
SELECT COUNT(ce.id) count_all, COUNT(IF(ce.course_id = 2, ce.id, NULL)) count_selected_course, c.date
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN courses_enrolled ce
    ON ce.registered_on BETWEEN c.date AND (c.date + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
GROUP BY c.date
ORDER BY c.date DESC;
```